# Why is carbon monoxide stable(compare with other flammable gas) in room temperature?

Tags: kinetics

I know carbon monoxide can burn with high temperature, but why doesn't it explode easily compared to other flammable or explosive gas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally hard to argue about kinetic parameters in such a broad comparison. Combustion mechanism of even simple compounds like methane contains several hundred (thousands) steps - so it is not a question about one or two elementary steps.

I would say CO has relative low energy content compared to the most flammable guesses due to the high oxygen content / oxidation state of carbon, and this thermodynamics is reflected in kinetics, too. It still can explode, though (comparison of explosive gas mixtures):
http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/explosive-concentration-limits-d_423.html

Comment: I would say CO energy content is not all that low; its molar [heat of combustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion#cite_ref-4) (see the last column) is about the same as that of hydrogen. So this is just kinetics. After all, $\mathrm{C\equiv O}$ is one of the strongest chemical bonds ever.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Whatever is the answer, "it is just kinetics", by definition. Hydrogen is a special case, as it has a very simple reaction mechanism. However if you compare CO to hydrocarbons, alcohols, ethers, the heat of combustion is low, either comparing the mass or the molar values.

Comment: I agree with your comparison, but object to your evaluation of hydrogen. Its reaction mechanism is not quite simple. Admittedly, it is simpler than that of hydrocarbons, but what if we compare it to CO? Just look at the number of possible reaction intermediates in both cases.

Comment: Maybe. Also, I think you should give the strengths of C-O bond as an answer,   no only as a comment. Note, bond energies and heat of combustion are not unrelated..

Comment: "It is just kinetics" is always true, but I think Ivan was saying it because thermodynamics is unrelated to kinetics.  Note the contrary and in my mind mistaken impression given by your answer: `"thermodynamics is reflected in kinetics"`

Comment: @CurtF. He might, but note that the core of his answer ( C≡O is a very strong bond) is essentially a thermodynamics argument.

Answer (score 2):

What gives you the impression that carbon monoxide does not burn easily?

Below I will link to a youtube video of an accidental ignition of a large amount of carbon monoxide.  But **be warned**!  The video is a highly uncontrolled, dangerous experiment.  The person who performed it did not have appropriate safety equipment and acted very recklessly.  ***DO NOT TRY TO PERFORM A SIMILAR EXPERIMENT YOURSELF*** unless you know what you are doing and have

1. A CO detector / alarm
2. A buddy in the room with you
3. A fire extinguisher
4. Lots of experience synthesizing gases using laboratory apparatus

...

---

OK, all that said, [here is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vAZcU4cjd4).  As you can see, carbon monoxide is quite flammable.  And that guy is an idiot, at least in my book.

The autoignition temperature of $\ce{CO}$ is ~609 °C, only 100 °C or so higher than the $\ce{H2}$ autoignition temperature, and lower than the autoignition temperature for solid carbon. The LEL and UEL are [12.5% and 74%, respectively](https://www.mathesongas.com/pdfs/products/Lower-(LEL)-&-Upper-(UEL)-Explosive-Limits-.pdf), which is a very wide range compared to most compounds.

Compared to other gases, $\ce{CO}$ explosions may be comparatively less violent because of the relatively smaller change in moles during the combustion reaction:

$$\ce{2CO(g) + O2(g) -> 2CO2(g)}$$

Thus, two moles of gas are formed from *three* moles of reactants, which means that the shock waves and pressure forces produced by a sudden $\ce{CO}$ combustion reaction / explosion are not as large as some gases such as say propane.

Comment: I guess OP was referring tot he fact that CO has one of the  narrowest LEL - UEL region at such lists you just showed.

Comment: Narrowest??  It's one of the widest.  On the list I linked to, only ethylene oxide, acetylene, and hydrogen (and deuterium) are wider, except for extremely reactive gases like diborane and trichlorosilane.  Most "everyday" explosive gases including methane, ethane, propane, ethylene, propylene, propylene oxide, hydrogen sulfide, hydrogen cyanide, all the butylenes, butadiene, and even carbonyl sulfide have much narrower ranges than carbon monoxide.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my mistake.